# Data Parallel Haskell Prefix Sum

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, multicore, data-parallel-haskell, prefix-sum

I'm playing with some Data Parallel Haskell code and found myself in need of a [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum).  However I didn't see any basic operator in the [dph package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dph-par/0.5.1.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Parallel.html) for prefix sum.

I rolled my own, but, since I'm new to dph, I'm not sure if it's properly taking advantage of parallelization:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelArrays #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fvectorise #-}

module PrefixSum ( scanP ) where
import Data.Array.Parallel (lengthP, indexedP, mapP, zipWithP, concatP, filterP, singletonP, sliceP, (+:+), (!:))
import Data.Array.Parallel.Prelude.Int ((<=), (-), (==), Int, mod)
-- hide prelude
import qualified Prelude 

-- assuming zipWithP (a -> b -> c) given 
-- [:a:] of length n and
-- [:b:] of length m, n /= m
-- will return
-- [:c:] of length min n m

scanP :: (a -> a -> a) -> [:a:] -> [:a:]
scanP f xs = if lengthP xs <= 1
                then xs
                else head +:+ tail
  where -- [: x_0, x_2, ..., x_2n :]
        evens = mapP snd . filterP (even . fst) $ indexedP xs
        -- [: x_1, x_3 ... :]
        odds = mapP snd . filterP (odd . fst)  $ indexedP xs
        lenEvens = lengthP evens
        lenOdds = lengthP odds
        -- calculate the prefix sums [:w:] of the pair sums [:z:]
        psums = scanP f $ zipWithP f evens odds
        -- calculate the total prefix sums as 
        -- [: x_0, w_0, f w_0 x_2, w_1, f w_1 x_4, ..., 
        head = singletonP (evens !: 0)
        body = concatP . zipWithP (\p e -> [: p, f p e :]) psums $ sliceP 1 lenOdds evens
        -- ending at either
        --    ... w_{n-1}, f w_{n-1} x_2n :]
        -- or
        --    ... w_{n-1}, f w_{n-1} x_2n, w_n :]
        -- depending on whether the length of [:x:] is 2n+1 or 2n+2
        tail = if lenEvens == lenOdds then body +:+ singletonP (psums !: (lenEvens - 1)) else body

-- reimplement some of Prelude so it can be vectorised
f $ x = f x
infixr 0 $
(.) f g y = f (g y)

snd (a,b) = b
fst (a,b) = a

even n = n `mod` 2 == 0
odd n = n `mod` 2 == 1
```

Comment: Hmm, is it even parallelizable?  Seems like a pretty serial idea, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @luqui: The parallel prefix sum algorithm for an array of size `n` takes `O(log n)` parallel rounds of computation.  There are two phases.  In the forward phase, given `{a_i | i \in [0,2n-1] }` you calculate `{ a_2i + a_{2i+1} | i \in [0,n-1] }` using `n/2` parallel additions.  In the backward phase, given `{ \sum_0^{2i+1} a_j | i \in [0,n-1] }` and `{ a_i | i \in [0,2n-1] }`, you calculate `{ \sum_0^i a_j | i \in [0, 2n-1 }` using `n/2` parallel additions.

Comment: @luqui: naturally, this only works properly for associative `+`, since there's the inherent assumption that `(a_0 + a_1) + (a_2 + a_3) == ((a_0 + a_1) + a_2) + a_3`

Comment: For a normal array, this would be `scanl`, but I'm not seeing that in dph-par.

Comment: right. scanl is O(n) work in O(n) time, scanP is meant to be O(n) work in O(log n) time.

Comment: Well... do the benchmarks agree with your expected numbers?  That's not the best, but certainly a viable, way to determine if you are doing work in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel prefix scans are [supported](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dph-prim-par/0.6.1.1/doc/html/Data-Array-Parallel-Unlifted.html#g:8), in fact, they're rather fundamental. So just pass `(+)` as your associative operator.